# How to trigger an event in the decorated part of the frame?

Tags: java, window-decoration

I would like to trigger an event when the mouse is in the decorated part of the frame. Is it possible in Java ?

I tried to add listeners to the frame, to the panel, etc and i tried with several methods but nothing works. And it works fine when i'm *in* the Frame

thank you for your help

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  a Jpanel and embed the components inside this Panel.And then write your code in mouseEntered Event. (The Events can be found  By  :

```
1)Right click on the  panel.

2)Select  Properties and select events tab and mouse enterd event.
```